# Query run in SQL against a linked server never completes

Tags: sql-server, advantage-database-server

I have 2 servers, Server A is SQL Express with a linked server connection to server B running Advantage.

The linked server set up is fine, and I can see all the tables from Server B via the linked server in Server A.

I can run a script using the execute at syntax to pull data from the linked server fine, eg this script runs in 11 seconds:

```
execute(' select pl_process, pl_barcode
from opt011d 
left join opt012d on pl_barcode = bc_key 
where pl_process in (''007'')

')

AT ADVANTAGE
```

I have a large script to run that requires several temp tables to run effeciently.

By adding INTO ##TEMP to the above the script never finishes..

```
execute(' select pl_process, pl_barcode
INTO ##TEMP
from opt011d 
left join opt012d on pl_barcode = bc_key 
where pl_process in (''007'')

')

AT ADVANTAGE
```

I have tried running the script with INTO TEMP (ie not a temp table)

```
execute(' select pl_process, pl_barcode
INTO TEMP
from opt011d 
left join opt012d on pl_barcode = bc_key 
where pl_process in (''007'')

')

AT ADVANTAGE
```

to store the results in a new table on Server B and the script does not finish, but if I look at the newly created table in Server B the info is all there. It just seems like SQL Express does not know that it's finished?

Has anyone delt with this before?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"By adding  `INTO ##TEMP`"*? `EXECUTE ({statement}) INTO {TABLE}` isn't valid syntax. Show us the actual query that is slow, not the fast one.

Comment: I've edited the question now. Thanks

Comment: SQL Server is at the mercy of the provider implementation here. According to the Advantage docs, "when the INTO clause is specified, the result set will be stored in the specified table and a live cursor will be returned" -- I'm pretty sure the SQL Server engine isn't expecting any kind of cursor, so that might be tripping it up. Try `select static pl_process, ...` to force a static cursor and see if that works, or else (if it allows multiple statements) a dummy `; select top 0 null` to produce an actual result set.